# Weird behavior of grouping in MySQL

Tags: mysql, django-orm

I have a such table in MySQL Database:

```
CREATE TABLE metrics (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  date date NOT NULL,
  value int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

With the following values:

```
INSERT INTO metrics (date, value)
VALUES 
    ('2022-04-01', 1),
    ('2022-04-02', 1),
    ('2022-04-03', 1),
    ('2022-04-04', 1),
    ('2022-04-05', 1),
    ('2022-04-06', 1),
    ('2022-04-07', 1),
    ('2022-04-08', 1),
    ('2022-04-09', 1),
    ('2022-04-10', 1),
    ('2022-04-11', 1),
    ('2022-04-12', 1),
    ('2022-04-13', 1),
    ('2022-04-14', 1);
```

I want to get sum of values grouping by weeks. Default week in MySQL is from Monday to Sunday, but I need to get grouping by week from Sunday to Saturday, so this is my query:

```
SELECT
    (DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL WEEKDAY(date) DAY) - INTERVAL 86400000000 MICROSECOND) AS week_start,
    SUM(value) AS value__sum
FROM
    metrics
GROUP BY
    (DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL WEEKDAY(date) DAY) - INTERVAL 86400000000 MICROSECOND)
ORDER BY
    week_start ASC;
```

`INTERVAL 86400000000 MICROSECOND` this interval is so strange because Django ORM do this. Anyway, I got such result:

```
week_start         |value__sum|
-------------------+----------+
2022-03-27 00:00:00|         3|
2022-04-03 00:00:00|         7|
2022-04-10 00:00:00|         4|
```

As you can see `week_start` value is right, it's Sunday but `value__sum` contains data in wrong period Monday-Sunday.
Perhaps I've missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```sql
SELECT
    DATE_SUB(
      date, INTERVAL WEEKDAY(DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL -1 DAY)) DAY
    ) AS week_start,    
    SUM(value) as value__sum
FROM
    metrics
GROUP BY
    week_start
ORDER BY
    week_start ASC;
```

I subtracted the day inside of `WEEKDAY`.

This results in:

| week_start | value__sum |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-03-27 | 2 |
| 2022-04-03 | 7 |
| 2022-04-10 | 5 |

Comment: Yes, your variant works properly. Even use `MICROSECOND`. It looks like my query is not correct. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use week(). If this is not splitting on the right day you can use `week(date_add, interval 1 day))` replacing 1 with the number (positive or negative) that you need.

> ```
> select
>   week(date) "week",
>   sum(value) "value"
> from metrics
> group by week(date)
> order by week(date);
> ```
>
> ```
> week | value
> ---: | ----:
>   13 |     2
>   14 |     7
>   15 |     5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7557e23496ae09429cbdbc4eb321bccd)*

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mentioned that I need to get date of week start in results too. But overall your query works properly, thank you!